# Avast's ASWARDISK causing Windows to not start

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod, bootrepair, system-repair-disc

After creating a Linux bootable USB, I noticed that at start up I got an error message from avastui.exe **The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005) Click Ok to close the application.**

The creation of the bootable USB might have had nothing to do with it and was probably just a coincidence.

To fix the issue, I reinstalled Avast.

Later when I tried to install mirc, I got an error message that it could not complete the installation. I thought "hmm wierd"...and restarted the computer.

At the" Windows starting" screen, it went back to restart, showing me the recovery menu screen.

I selected safe mode but it would still not start...but rather goes back to the recovery menu after a few seconds in the Windows logo starting screen.

I noticed during the drivers load list when attempting to start at safe mode, it stops at `\windows\system32\drivers\Aswardisk.sys`, and then restarts (boot loop).

Another thing to note is a momentary, split second flicker of BSOD right after the Windows starting screen before proceeding to restart.

**Things I've tried to remedy this issue:**

1. Last known configuration (advanced).
2. Startup repair through Windows installation disc. (No restore points so couldn't do that).
3. Booted through Linux liveUSB and deleted the Avast folder in programs folder.
4. `chkdsk c: /r` (I get "failed to transfer logged messages status 50 superuser" at the end).

None of the above methods changed anything.

Could someone PLEASE help? Needless to say, I don't want to do a clean install because I need my files.

Thank you so much!